# UV Mapping OpenGL with OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv, opengl, glut, opengl-3

I cannot get a image from an OpenCV image to get mapped onto a 2D plane in OpenGL. Whenever I try to render the image onto the plane using the code below, I get a yellow plane instead of the actual image on it.

```
// My Init code
cv::Mat mat(640, 480, CV_8UC3, cv::Scalar(255, 0, 0));

GLuint tid = 0;
if (tid != 0)
{
    glDeleteTextures(1, &tid);
}

glGenTextures(1, &tid);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, tid);

glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, mat.cols, mat.rows, 0, GL_BGR, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, (void*)mat.data);
glGenerateMipmap(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);

glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
```

.

```
// My Render Code
{
    glPushMatrix();
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glTranslatef(0, 0, 0);

    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, tid);

    GLfloat sq_vert[] = {-1, -1, 1, -1, 1, 1, -1, 1};
    glVertexPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, sq_vert);
    glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);

    GLfloat sq_tex[] = {0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1};
    glTexCoordPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, sq_tex);
    glEnableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);

    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_FAN, 0, 4);

    glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    glDisableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);

    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);

    glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    glPopMatrix();
}
```

[image]

Comment: Where is the OpenCV image (`mat`) loaded or generated? The image in the question is a completely yellow image.

Comment: Hey @Rabbid76, Sorry, I had 255, 255, 0 as the default values of the OpenCV Mat but no matter what I do whether I change the defaults to 255,0,0 or 0,0,255 or even cv::imread an image from my machine, I still get a yellow texture.

Comment: How are you planning on using the fixed-function matrix stack with OpenGL ES 2.0?

Comment: Hey @genpfault, I'm a completely lost on what you mean. I'm not that experienced in OpenGL and have been trying to cludge up a UV mapping from tutorials I find online.

Comment: Well, OpenGL ES 2.0 removed fixed-function matrix stack functions like `glPushMatrix()` & `glTranslatef()` in favor of generic vertex attributes so I'm not sure how your code is even compiling if you aren't using some sort of shim/compatibility library.

Comment: @genpfault I'm so sorry! I must be using straight OpenGL and not ES. I have removed the tags.

Comment: Aah, that'd do it then :)

Answer (score 2):

I solved my issue.. I needed to run the initialize() code I had above in the same thread that I init'd the OpenGL Context.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you reset the current color state back to RGB(1.0, 1.0, 1.0) with a `glColor()` call before you draw your texture, otherwise the default `GL_MODULATE` [texture environment](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glTexEnv.xml) will multiply all your texel colors with the current color state, most likely yellow from your debug text.

Or switch to `GL_DECAL` which ignores the current color state entirely.

Comment: Thanks for this info! Now I have a white texture but still, no image mapped onto it. The result should be a red texture because of OpenCV mat being initialized to (255, 
 0, 0). I must be missing something but I don't know what..

Comment: @MoeBataineh: Time for a [mcve] then, though double-check that `tid` is non-zero after the `glGenTextures()` call.